# Debian: Nextcloud : Can't create or write into the data directory /mnt/disk0/nextcloud-data/

Tags: debian, permissions, docker, chmod, nextcloud

I installed nexcloud on my debian install. When I run:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 nextcloud
```

I get some random hash. Than I go to `localhost:8080` where is set up screen. I fill up all textboxes and select postgresql.

When I hit *finish setup* I go back to set up screen with message:

> Can't create or write into the data directory /mnt/disk0/nextcloud-data/

What should I do make it work and set up normally ?
Thank you for help

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Have you checked that the directory is writeable by the app?

Comment: @roaima less clear as this is docker. It's referring to a directory inside the image, which isn't immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed something in your question.  That directory isn't used by Nextcloud by default so I guess you set the `NEXTCLOUD_DATA_DIR` environment variable (mentioned on the [dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud) ).

As this is docker things inside the docker container cannot see your host system.  They have an entirely different file system all of their own.

What you can do is to mount a directory from your host system inside the container.  So if it was your intention to run Nextcloud using `/mnt/disk0/nextcloud-data/` as your data directory you can do something like this:

```
sudo NEXTCLOUD_DATA_DIR=/data docker run -d -p 8080:80 --mount type=bind,source=/mnt/disk0/nextcloud-data,target=/data nextcloud
```

This tells nextcloud to use `/data` and tells docker to bind `/mnt/disk0/nextcloud-data/` to `/data` inside nextcloud's container.

*I've just checked and it seems that Nextcloud runs as `www-data` (`33`) inside the container.  So you may need to set permissions on that directory first.*